# Google App Engine error “Upstream sent too big header”

Tags: nginx, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-standard

I am running a Laravel app with Google App Engine Standard PHP 7.2, with Elfinder package.

Today, I receive 502 error while trying to access Elfinder. Upon analyzing the log, I found this particular error:

> 96 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: , request: "GET
>   /xxx/elfinder/connector?_token=XXX", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/google-config/php-fpm.sock:", host: "XXX",
>   referrer: "XXX".

After googling for similar problem, I found out it is probably a problem with nginx proxy_buffer_size.

Based on several suggestion, I try to migrate to flex env and create nginx-app.conf which contains:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
}
```

But still, the problem persist. Even after I modify the all value to 512k, which is probably unnecessarily large, and tried to turn off proxy and fastcgi buffering.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try shrinking the [header size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280027/is-there-a-size-limit-for-http-response-headers-on-google-app-engine) until it fits.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know what is the content of the header that is being sent. I don't know how to shrink it.